# Want to change unallocated to fresh space

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I already have windows 8 and I want to install ubuntu 14.04 on my system (first time). As because of unallocated partition, it showed unusable, while installation of ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the livecd and open gparted, create an ext4 partition and then use that. Unless the whole disk is "free space" I am not sure how well ubuntu installer handles it.

Comment: there is no gparted. Please see the edited question.

Comment: there is gparted on the livecd for the installer, and if you are talking about setting up windows 8 with dual boot and already resized the windows partition from there that would create the unallocated space

Comment: ya you are right. I got 120gb unallocated but while installation, it showing unusable instead of fresh space. So I am not able to select that partition.

Comment: create a partition there with gparted, as the way some windows partitioners do it is they just resize the other partition and mark the other space as being used by an "unknown partition type" that they recognize as free space but gparted thinks is a partition

Comment: I already did the partition in my windows 8 system, for the installation of ubuntu 14.04. But I want to use that partition for the ubuntu 14.04 installation, why I need gparted, i.e. what I am not able to understand.

Comment: Gparted is a partition editor that is much more capable of dealing with a variety of filesystems, including ntfs. Create a new EXT4 partition in Gparted in the space that the windows partitioner marked as "unpartitioned" and ubuntu assumed meant "unavailable"

Comment: Thanks, let me try this. you mean to say that I need to create extFAT, for ubuntu installation in Windows 8. Will it not work on NTFS

Comment: use the ubuntu installer cd, go into "try ubuntu", open the dash and search for gparted (it does not run on windows) and then create  an "ext4", not extfat partition. EXT4 is not fat based, it is used mainly for linux and unix systems as a more stable substitute to fat based fs